# Simulating person selecting text using Java Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, webdriver

For an automated test I'm trying to simulate a user clicking on some text, moving the mouse pointer several times, then releasing the mouse button.

When I do it as a user, I see text selected (highlighted), and the selection moves with the mouse pointer.

When I do it with Selenium, I see... nothing.

Here's sample code. The page I'm working on has a span tag surrounding each word of the text, so every word has its own web element. startSelect and endSelect are two such WebElements.

```
    public void doSomeMouseStuff() throws InterruptedException {
        Actions actions = new Actions(getDriver());

        actions
        .moveToElement(startSelect)
        .clickAndHold()
        .perform();

        actions
        .moveToElement(endSelect)
        .perform();

        try {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 5, 1000);
            wait.until(Predicates.<WebDriver> alwaysFalse());
        }
        catch(TimeoutException e) {
            //Ignore the timeout.  It's what we *want* to happen.
        }

        actions
        .release()
        .perform();
    }
```

I've thought of injecting Javascript to select text, but that misses the point; later the page will be doing things with those mouse clicks and drags, and my test needs to look like a user clicking and dragging.

How can I get Webdriver to actually simulate a user selecting text?

Comment: Try whole action in one line as `actions.moveToElement(startSelect).clickAndHold().moveToElement(endSelect).release().perform()` and look, may be it works..

Comment: Putting all the actions in one line doesn't highlight the text either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best I am able to tell, Webdriver doesn't interact with the browser as a user would, so selecting text using it is out.

On the bright side, by injecting some Javascript event listeners on the page I was able to determine that Webdriver does in fact fire the appropriate Javascript events.

Since our function will be using Javascript events to drive its behavior, this outcome is good enough, and I can proceed.

Thanks to all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

might be a little bit tricky, and it might not working, but worth to has a try

think about using these two method

`moveToElement(WebElement toElement, int xOffset, int yOffset)`

`moveByOffset(int xOffset, int yOffset)`

get the offset of startElement,
get the offset of endElement,
you need to calculate the offset you want between startElement and endElement

```
action.moveToElement(startSelect).clickAndHold()
.moveByOffset()//you need to input the x, y you calculate previously yourself here
.moveByOffset()
.moveByOffset()
.moveByOffset()
.moveByOffset()
.moveByOffset()
.moveToElement(endSelect)
.release()
.build()
.perform();
```